# How to restart Alsa/PulseAudio after using Jack

Tags: linux, alsa, pulseaudio, reboot, jack

After I use Jack, the PulseAudio outputs and inputs are replaced by a dummy device. I've tried to kill PulseAudio and reload Alsa, but the only way I can use an Alsa-based application again is to reboot. I know that there must be a way to fix the problem without rebooting. I have had this problem in multiple Linux distros, including Ubuntu and currently Fedora 19.

Output of `service alsa-utils restart`:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  alsa-utils.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit alsa-utils.service failed to load:
No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status
alsa-utils.service' for details.
```

And `systemctl status alsa-utils.service`:

```
alsa-utils.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

`alsactl kill quit` and `alsactl init` proceed with no errors.

Comment: You don't mention your distribution but assuming you are using a `sysv` one, does `service alsa-utils restart` help?

Comment: @terdon, I edited my question to include the distros. No, it just gives an error.

Comment: @bntser What is the error message? Always copy-paste error messages.

Comment: [`pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`](https://askubuntu.com/a/230893/349837) works for me, and when I messed with pulseaudio setup [`mv ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse.old` solved the problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/23081/349837).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simpler than it appeared. The output of `fuser -v /dev/snd/*` revealed jackd was silently hogging the audio card even after QjackCtl supposedly killed it. Running `killall jackd` fixed the problem. The problem wasn't with PulseAudio, but rather jackd running invisibly in the background.